# Mergemap Angular + firestore collection

Tags: typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I'm starting to use angular and I would need help to solve this problem. I'm using a firestore database.

```
  getDiveSitesFrequentation(userId: string): void {
   this.getDives(userId)
    .pipe(map(dives => mergeMap(
     (dive: Dive) => this.diveSiteService.getDiveSite(dive.dive_site)
     .pipe(map(diveSite => { return dive.number + ' ' + diveSite.name }))
     ))).subscribe(v => console.log(v))
```

I need the console log return an array of string with the dive number and the dive site name.

but this code return only the mergemap function.

Somebody can help me about this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `this.diveSiteService.getDiveSite` do? It returns an Observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right path, I believe this will give you what you want:

```
  import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

  ...

  this.getDives(userId)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(dives => {
        const diveSiteStringObservables = dives.map(
          (dive: Dive) => {
            return this.diveSiteService.getDiveSite(dive.dive_site)
              .pipe(
                map(diveSite => {
                  return dive.number + ' ' + diveSite.name;
                })
              );
          }
        );
        return combineLatest(diveSiteStringObservables);
      })
    ).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

The key is to use combineLatest() to combine an array of Observables into a single Observable returning an Array.

Comment: Hello @SnorreDan, thank you for your answer. I have tried your code and I receive the following error: `TypeError: "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable."`

Comment: Looks like i forgot to add a "return" on line 10 in my code, I have updated the line now to "return this.diveSiteService.getDiveSite(dive.dive_site)". Hopefully it should work now.